# Image from IntBuffer Java

Tags: java, image

I have the RGB data for an image in an `IntBuffer` and want to have it displayed via painting onto a `JPanel`. What is the most effective way to do this?

Edit

Am currently drawing the data onto a `BufferedImage` via the following code, but would like to know if there exists a faster method:

```
Raster raster= image.getData();
intBuffer.get( ((DataBufferInt) raster.getDataBuffer()).getData() );
image.setData(raster);
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the int array from the IntBuffer and using this to set an appropriately sized BufferedImage's raster via `setData(...)`? Or use the BufferedImage constructor that takes a Raster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int[] rgb = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Then just copy the contents of your IntBuffer into the rgb array and paint the BufferedImage. Any change to the array will directly change the image. Of course the image needs to have the correct dimensions.